# Any way to check whether antivirus is installed on Mac and is up-to-date by code?

Tags: node.js, macos, shell, antivirus

I have an ElectornJS application running on Mac computer.

I want to check whether any antivirus software is installed on a computer running this ElectronJS application.
I also want to check whether, if exists, it is up-to-date.
I don't have predefined list of anti-virus softwares to check because I don't care what Anti-Virus is installed. All I care is that there is one installed.

Any advice? I must implement it with code tho. No manual check.

I do know I can check it on Windows computers with the following command:
`wmic /node:localhost /namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 path AntiVirusProduct Get DisplayName | findstr /V /B /C:displayName || echo No Antivirus installed`

But how can I do the same for Mac computers?

Comment: Well for a start your code on windows won't work for every virus product

Comment: @Liam assume I have a well-defined list of supported products for my application.

Comment: Well without knowing what this well defined list is how are we supposed to know how they install on Mac? Having written a commercial product that does a very similar job (for mac and windows) and can tell you that each case is subtly different and there is no one answer to this question

Comment: @Liam My bad. There is no list at all. All I want is to check that there is any Anti-Virus software installed on the computer. I don't care what one. I can't inject malicious test code.